# Align column values in SQR

Tags: oracle, report, sqr

I'm trying to align the column values, but they are of different lengths. I can't just use `Print '123' (+1, 9)` and then `Print '123456' (+1, 9)` because it'll look something like this:

```
123456790123456790123456790123456790123456790123456790 <- Ignore this line
       123
       123456
```

Notice how the right most numbers aren't aligned with each other. I want the output to be like this:

```
123456790123456790123456790123456790123456790123456790 <- Ignore this line
     123
  123456
```

So I would want to stop printing at a certain index. How would I achieve this using SQR?

I tried `Print '123' (+1, 9)` and `Print '1234' (+1, 9)` but it gives the wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SQR, but here's a suggestion: as SQR supports the LPAD function (see [String functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/SQRLG/ch03s74s03s03.html)):

> Pads the source_value on the left to a length of length_value using
>   pad_value and returns the result.
>
> Syntax: dst_var = lpad(source_value, length_value, pad_value)

you could apply it to strings you print. For example (once again: note that I don't know SQR, you might need to adjust it):

```
Print lpad('123', 6, ' ') (+1, 9)
```

which would make `...123` (each dot represents a space).

Why LPAD to 6 characters in length? Well, because your other string ('123456') is 6 characters long. Change it, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like you want to end the value in column 9.  The lPad function will not work for this because (+1,9) says START in column 9.  Also, you can't put the lPad function into the print statement.

Instead use the Edit parameter of print starting in column 1:

```
Print 123    (+1,1) edit 999999999
Print 123456 (+1,1) edit 999999999
```

Now that works great for numbers but it also works well for strings as long as they contain numbers.  So this works too:

```
Print '123'    (+1,1) edit 999999999
Print '123456' (+1,1) edit 999999999
```

I have tested these statements in SQR and they work, however, this will produce ugly results:

```
Print 'ABC'    (+1,1) edit 999999999
Print 'ABCDEF' (+1,1) edit 999999999
```

If you have to print strings not numbers, then use the lPad command to format the variable:

```
Let $String = lPad($String, 9, ' ')
Print $String (+1,1) ! <--- start at column 1
```